# AngularJS: sending event to another controller and redirecting to new location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I am trying to switch to a new view and send an event that another controller (the one managing the new view) should intercept and elaborate.

The current controller, in the meantime, is sending an HTTP request, whose response shall be passed as an argument to the event. Here's the code of the first controller:

```
// do some stuff and initialize FIND_URL and nextpage variables 
$http.get(FIND_URL).success(function(response) { 
    details = response;
    $rootscope.$broadcast('detailsReceived', details);
});

$location.path(nextpage);
```

FIND_URL is built appending a parameter to a base URL.
The event is correctly sent. The other controller is the following:

```
appName.controller("otherController", function($rootScope) {
    console.log("Initialize");
    $rootScope.$on('detailsReceived', function(event, details) {
        console.log("EventReceived");
        if(details) {
            $scope.localDetails = details;
        }
    });
});
```

The controllers are unrelated: each html page refers to one controller.
However, the event is not received by otherController, which is however initialized. Also, nextpage is correctly shown, but is is empty, of course, as details are not in its scope due to the event not being received.
I also tried using $scope rather than $rootScope, but I have the same issue: no event received.

I cannot use a service.

I must be mistaken, but I don't see where. Can you help me?

Comment: This whole design feels wrong.. why do you say you can't use a service?

Comment: I am using the same approach in another point, where the same controller, which is now sending the event, actually is receiving the event of a third controller. There it works. Not using a service is a constraint I am given.

Comment: Are you sure that the event is actually broadcasted and you $https.get succeeds?

Comment: Well, yes , i get some console output i inserted into the success

Comment: not using a service seems like an arbitrary constraint; what sense does it make to tell someone they have to come up with a solution but not use a resource designed specifically to perform the task?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

1) Move the get request to the second controller
2) Change routing by adding the parameter used to build FIND_URL as URL parameter
3) Use $routeParams to access the passed parameter in the second controller.